# Curl command is not working in push sending

Tags: angularjs, curl, ionic-framework

Hi i  am creating app in which push notification is to be implemented but at the time  of  4> send push the below command line is giving error.
following is my profile information 
DEV_DEVICE_TOKEN: The one you copied from your apps log=DEV-8423e4fd-f7fa-4bfd-b56b-f904dfc8035a

PROFILE_NAME: The name of your security profile=profile

API_TOKEN: The API token you created=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI3MmI2MTkyMy0zOTA4LTRhNDQtOWNhMC1hMjNhMzQ0ODM4ZGQifQ.1XVYY3Cf5F8NJ9qmcHz4Xxk6MZU_DZSKXzGQUcSFExo

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI3MmI2MTkyMy0zOTA4LTRhNDQtOWNhMC1hMjNhMzQ0ODM4ZGQifQ.1XVYY3Cf5F8NJ9qmcHz4Xxk6MZU_DZSKXzGQUcSFExo" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "tokens": ["DEV-8423e4fd-f7fa-4bfd-b56b-f904dfc8035a"],
    "profile": "profile",
    "notification": {
        "message": "This is my demo push!"
    }
}' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"
```

and this is the error i am getting

```
C:\Users\lenovo>curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI3MmI2MTkyMy0zOTA4LTRhNDQtOWNhMC1hMjNh
MzQ0ODM4ZGQifQ.1XVYY3Cf5F8NJ9qmcHz4Xxk6MZU_DZSKXzGQUcSFExo" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

C:\Users\lenovo>    "tokens": ["DEV-8423e4fd-f7fa-4bfd-b56b-f904dfc8035a"],
'"tokens":' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\lenovo>    "profile": "profile",
'"profile":' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\lenovo>    "notification": {
'"notification":' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\lenovo>        "message": "This is my demo push!"
'"message":' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\lenovo>    }
'}' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\lenovo>}' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"
```

my other commands of curl is running it means my crul is working proprely
but for this it is showing this error
how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

The shell is interpreting each line as a new command.

Either combine all of the commands into a single line, or place a `\` at the end of each line to let the shell know that the command is not finished, like this:

```
    curl -X POST -H "Authorization: <snip>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ \
        "tokens": ["<snip>"], \
        "profile": "profile", \
        "notification": { \
            "message": "This is my demo push!" \
        } \
    }' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"
```

Also if your real auth info you will  need to change it, as somebody else may use it!

Edit: On Windows, the character to put at the end of each line is `^`, so it should be instead:

```
    curl -X POST -H "Authorization: <snip>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ ^
        "tokens": ["<snip>"], ^
        "profile": "profile", ^
        "notification": { ^
            "message": "This is my demo push!" ^
        } ^
    }' "https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications"
```

Hope this helps!